# Extend Video recording time in Google Glass

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way we can extend the default video recording time on glass. The current recording time is only 10 seconds and  we have to extend it manually by pressing the camera key for one second or by tapping and choosing Extend Video option. So i was wondering whether there is a flag that we can set when requesting the camera to start recording which will cause the camera to record an extended video.

I was also wondering how can we set the maximum time limit of video recording and what is the default time limit of video recording in glass ?

I am using the code below for starting the glass camera for video recording

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Also if there isn't a possible way can anyone guide me on the alternatives. Is there any open source camera available which works for glass  or should i have to write my own camera [any links that would help me get started] ?

Answer (score 3):

Hope you get him idea from it:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 60);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This above code video duration is one minute,if u want to extend the video time then do it like that,and now the video duration is 2 minutes:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 120);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: I think this specifies the maximum time duration of video recording. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT

 In my case i want to disable the glass default 10 seconds video recording limit so this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the camera directly and record the video yourself. See the official Android documentation for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video